# Longest (more or less) ideal subsequence

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

An ideal subsequence is a subsequence of a string, where the distance between adjacent characters in the subsequence is bounded by a maximum, i.e. \$\lvert c[i] - c[i\pm 1] \rvert \leq k\$

Example:

Input:

```
s = "acfgbd"
k = 2
```

Output:

```
4
```

Explanation: The longest ideal subsequence is "acbd". The length of this string is 4, so 4 is returned.
Note that "acfgbd" is not ideal because 'c' and 'f' have a difference of 3 in alphabetical order.

I've tried to go with a dynamic programming answer and cache previous comparisons in a dictionary but it's far too slow with this input:

```
s = "mymqqhdyknqqtaiefwthqnpkipzjknqhmelmdoxxxozemfyyqyzlkosepmyvacbzqjzkpultyfazpumdsscqtenuagyrtagfjkjkrairafqlsolzlwwkcyblruwxstmyeyrjkgukwirewnonknjjwskhkoohwlbsaewyjaegnfouuksycrxsibjfqbhmhedcthnbiepywatalhlittczssztjcvjvsmxbvppdxpdlppkgimsfiemzsuocawhkqlsmedyxwaivebsneqapjmhienddnkiitbobangijfsdmbywqxjyjykumsdyolqgvcemvrdfzuicqfheyzixlqhpkucnkbunirlcdipekzgriwndplvdypmwzuasjkwairtzcneepvmuqgcqqdqpmbvmnprdepmgrzzvqgvoowhvbnqpohuifwkmtciledsutwhatcnbzyxemxhqontnkinzziqwkbqurysomviaunriilsjehvlfofhawtqxvixeqctanratlpsrooptdxvjcvpbmefetbzkapaextimcsernnizzesdwneqhwenhsqapbebxuicahoxfxxvhcnrmhlythajyhdcyeinwlkpvwjowuehtcfpmywnlceulsqqjblaglyznmzrvfzlsgkjyvyfsioweeoilxejiselbhrlupfaevbimgarksevcgjcrurtqgsvsmaumlzpulbbtvuqyvggyqemfwyazyasphvgdlbmvdlkhcbgbftevywgrtuyyrjmqoguusmwhpsocafisctosfhqlvbbdvwiipeqyprzfpfflrblhenesjlrlfueyexgmwmcadfnqwhabuesjhvfaciqdppguliwmbvothxyxffvcmjtkkvaalhlnpwsaawmfhgrmjlumhoxpqpsetiwtyzxiypvymsvscsudtjrkwpeavsfcgtrrxyombdxmtfjkfkibpoykcfhwzhcevepcoytdfoqdryyblzeeoupckccovjhryylgypkkolkcahigwuvpktlwoqjmouxgggieksgqagajxlzpcobjaoztxjmnxnwvfnjmykuimrzpuxucfcjnrgxapuyapueghxqsgcsfdepmnrwtjuwgggyzxcwpnvdbwvrtntldpqtqqgjwthtqmgmppbzcuhfsatounawolifqdtyszekcghqnyznihaqhdixnntlybmjefegmetnskeuflhfifuemejiufijcfgcjaksjmgfzrlsceawrhbaynqiyrcdomqiuelshkazdesrfuttqayfigdatzepudmymrnsyrgkhicpjgdprgqutqzwgghsssgnejvzrfecbnvojamzqosracuzqwmjtovkyqurckfgifcjohpljklqfjbzqoriyzaiywznxcnlfjldinkdrcyoglfdakklvmvozcgtjgokhkayyxkruwhplhflbgbhgvuoiakxettrzvgjxwxkhqfhspjmtyrvjsjxllseiakoryuuzgxcjrzofkwrtdcvsukzmwijuvxtgeivnfvqicbgzcwycvselqqnsciqkxvlhqtnyufjchxsknrtsfpazxohiumvgraemhajoocpdtxwlpijgrykivfcxpqzkquhegspjeclpuchxqktgosokrycrfuzuvzplkgthntvcmphiwwgvtqechedwyqpvoecocvudhsuasgqjjgxzilsjiighozpvlwopbiatfzshmzbgwmmvwzsqebtfpjvmvmddhpmftyunwwuplxodqhmklgmllvcgpiuactzbatmnmknhjbsooigcujrsrjttimmlksgbldrlfrghgiyocbtnpofvdmwvizgckambvolsucdgcvdroprtzboeahmxllmxkwspisrhtstuhgtaxrjzyrlzrhsiulzwjftnzupguufcgqptsyklllgtobxfwyajxcdpwaoeqonqnmqlubjvwnxhaiiilnvncpvfxfkwipapmcuiezqaybygjmvitywrlhsgnemtzntvsbzydonegbqnvpuajnxqplknobtnekcjmfdpeupwffmjgyajnkmxsnacigyomjpkthmithabqsuhufmlfvuyzchlnasaxaospgbzxpbpahnqknfefmywnfbnhscihmjepiwekuqkymwgxfanyhkdamybkpmlbwkgnxrntvemspzqpgbqjfkmgfdvdgvpywrmmsrfnzqalkssvsveudzipgizkeisuxayqaqlgzgkixmiykeomvusneckfoxbubpbninnugqaashlzapmydeysbgobpjkqenuleqrerovclwdyljvzuhcpaiuzrgnvdvukrtauzgkjspkwfcwvuenudysydvhptqmberormkgfatvmscatafwvwjvmyvztqncuxisbekjuyrmaymkqameyzhkkwfdzwrltsudrzmylrigecrkoehdrixgiqejgmomeuexfnrjnrgtogmxqimnnxuqhinmiayacqtokuekpclfvtnludopglqduviwjvmzkxpkghtdvigxqmfmqnedogiuhdnrxphskhrxmwnklshisgccpdqoykjzjcpqafgzvwzfpwgvlvrsbisopfwzmbnevxdhqaotqzsemyuwmkgvfqsafbyefwieqzfkbljytuucufvdjbiulxmxqzseunsesxgpegimefvxkmnsqctmmzxocvgbmpsbzeiuqnojvcnrtscgnoibdawjgmlqroeckxmpartkqdlbqfiyukovuoprhsrzyjwkcoknnkinwcjogmclttqwhfqrgrnbymrahgzdmikpbqgtniwrourtchgmijxnsjrqbvgrpxichmwfidbmpwxstuukcldveqttjjrdqwqnhiuhomgovcfbxaqsvqyyscpgxjaihexwhflnluxxttikurcrbznagzzuiwstommflwidgfusszkzlpbnxrkhthclefwcpjjifxslgsyamjumgovdncxjnbzqowxctbkqfciqmgtgxprrjrbnyxlmtaqoiozxtzldcwlzulknfvryzhblcbmgentzgrjaobwrpsysfikvvzjbahkopxmcgadihbbdfktekqlnaoogedofvgaouzdpwlxhaenrdwccnnwwetzcjxhqwwjidotnycitjshdocahdxcxgqpgyqzegjzpzdgylbznubfgsvjgvxgovtnfuuiowvzrbgggfpikleqifckhoieadtuuewsedkeguuyzjdhgywoykfbfnktimgofuyvqblwuaixnjyiymuuudjxxonoayxmyqzaheslxpbpqhgpoaibkkaucmdevvgndbkebxqajzjtgbmgeqwfydnfferriaysmivovrjehhpkwsfawogeoxxykhzarrqdimgdzvegvbksrvuvbwafumnzoypicaaecqhnwmzutmwagagxgqdcywnpdyzcgurmjhqevdnnphybotacpipdganlyumttddydwgksfxuxyjgejkkthitkfiglkzyknpjhrrzvvxgpawnltwyyjsobgsqgiepygsvfxsifnmrphtwklxcbfeghepoxzxxtihnkdwlzqwtvegocgygnqbvighsklipncymwsnbqyxrqzzglkgnylwaxkcpwdwsjcqcuhrphybupkiriewglexfyydoirgfqiafqonbcmopqqcyoivqxlkuxslfayuznqsjulmixafifjhcoxhfpltozteddxqswrntunycrnieczpvzdxrdethyomapechuxqmvhgcqqmrdzmdogrwyeujyhdmmioetiwiybgrqtsvknksvidmkdtdosstcdozbheubpfnoqrjmtobvnpflcpkecyoahifqexpzjqrwtmasesqsiuvgypyntpotbuwxwxapimshjyypmeksovwpmzkshlfyfiwohcwpyqkpkygbmvxldttmqqcohxfnpyexqqtcbnfsmkagehoattngxvjhxmlwpgkjxjwiszxbmfailiigkwxhprwmihrqzrblgfkintswktqdmcnbxikbowzoldrdkmnefphdmhrrpaqlaqhiognhooprbmmpzowgejmgcelkwxgfsawubmepayaqgrrynnemaiaxhzsecqkgehuasltkqnqhhanujfvvxsebllwwjagzfvngetiyvvcnjiycehrenfmrkylkdswidlmoapxfddwumyucuhiwebanbnikfbgiwumegcknvimjmyfzebtnwvzzgtwlbwtgvoaynhtvvpwspqaqxlyodyajkyuwwwqvdipjduowlwiarkjneorvahtafhugvujpmwrygzndagmdotiypofvnaiotraljmktqskhfullszowzlntudsqvpkfigqjohensyrboqokakerqsiymjlgtpmjoaczixmtddnineyncwnqggmnimtcyhzrfftyvommnjlnhshpawwbsvjpjcisrjmramikeqmmgibpbzkrjfasengkntpiqcluefpunjvwsqsapbyojicpuhmgbhyvuqogxwndmirtwzxnfvfczsrxefcmbkhkvofjpptpixzvvsumurarjiaxsjbsidrzwhluistirkergvvnzxqfsufkhrkenjckhmmglspzlqplbllpxsuvbrbmctfbxicbtzhiulssuoosmhuehuhlhcsjdpxpvdkdrlnkvjwvozhzkftekozmjejnbkyzpwyltzxanfqksxcfuzpqtwuwavmqecvpakdmwzbtidngnyxvvrsuulpenpmbvxkaxmswkyemsefnduscomifautmwpfnpidxeoatmoneybjxefvrmboibltkrveciloixzcxnbrclndnihlkdcausarknehmuspyozxdjvfcjnnhhlguxdkiqragncrdkinkzrhytjefcwapdmqspikfratxgkuxhlvweefkohunwfzdwbhcyujshydknbnrswoopkcdbmareuwlqojxsixnjuhdmsuqrpsxlniorfinmwwguorettbjwuyeemksjjzdroxicpcizaofhvqeqbwvlbgjhzkfzimvcgxyonwnixwfjhheooobrpjsteemxfuewgnxpdcotbkeriuzaxbwqidsgplmcmxdqpiqnkaujdmedwpnqmzhoedmmqplxstgsyiurpkotrfgndtqjyvjzondrtmlewrxvtjcpmaqtnsliibznrrngojbernfpnemdooduiyvnuczyqquqdthfffgpatbofqkfzvjcnvmximonkmdhxtgdzhevsknuqghvqznpgqoxgggwlazsjdklwdivooessifvhciecxoyjfcsjjngpjjpiojjlswbvztywyixrkxpkhadjxchlqbxxvediyoaxfdcjnpyohsfbflyjxmztymkwkokhbnjzamrvdgccfdlwxzzjztocsmvbjncnuvmusubbyjsnpkbglyydetcwrpbhejmfroikkbdkwjjiknstolbefkhpmusjturrolxqkyrpueuvtkrrlijwtkacjekiuqfjbkljsjxwzdyjvaafwgpxenbgupkanukljcxgqatuoxilsuqfrifjsrfidshhidetmfpopyrhzynuyuyhakzufgkazeiqvrohbjhywqxwdjzdiwwkqywclwuceizpkfzjkiffxvvfvivvhubdikumpdbjfotfpbhdfjohtqubkbahoytavdvmdebqzpuetksqhfcdydqcpmqrojglggumuffvyndocrgvkqixztyqxctwwuzmvvexzxfkxxnpdghoplmrvjhgardmsevqjvdbjlxopqtqzbeagdflmjfkrdndwjsskqfbiyftkscogocmiuumkzqnqiogqbwxebedivxcyqgwmhyzucjdevkgdewmiqcdotlaatyxskzeyxzxirypdndzhrjjlbvstvsvfygsoqtcmllnmifmzlhztcqkwmihmmghpaaedecxqadeucinbzsyeqccfttwpcvuafztouxjhwmhzxnadnsniwktzzbekztpnirnntkdeyiqryxkcfwbkyfbjjgjdrodehgqwpgnwbqmvizdxqcocjvhmuiaxczerxgyucdqmlvlacynucvmjkszxrkeoowaqzdrdcvioeqcykuwzsoeraochpomyvgisxvzcytddlkchookofsgtgigvukiphssauvpdkodgqsyoiqzbqjidypgnkukungkhzfzqmplyruxyamjauaqnpxnpjiwrxjsaoosywargyklgvpxbjzhwmopgxuuifniwidoeomqzmmtskhheomzooirazvxiwzkyplntzssowqhdceblmncytfmxdusskuhftlbrwuhdtzseatlffiwsqbgytnyngisiznwowjonpeegibxtleivhvsuxwuxmjnftkwvtlffktszvdfxmgxtkfkbkswavimojatocfytamaexuccxmlmiygbfsqzqqwkymlpmtctjhnmfqtpuecjoqbymdsnlrjgdfhaagpztvlylqhqcmxssednizromzizmkhksppcuxkabaimsbcmyyrjygbhggawighrxeonueefvpswgkgvphrqbelnhavjqrxjgazvbfzzjtftedjefsvfpxqsmfbzryknhxfbkxtqpkqdrwyxnhpzwgyyxxjrfjrzfgmmrgljxnfllvyasacvrtpedewzuryxwecefxqwiebswbzfyrnyqeyjrzozpfhlsqzneuxzbbtjuwlflqasthrphcegeafjvtlcyokadqvayhmxsirhzdbojlrvbjtdexpmledbpifuyarqebzutocomtvidmtxeghbczoegnehazbslavqvwzuluzyimojdlbnrtvrsbycijfrubcvhmhmblumfsmxeatiynzhrdhuypuzuwcukyhvpwesolpkvsfxmocufsezfllqikszgdmdsbljminbdskiumymgvnvvvokcmkrpwiphahyjctggfjfbuezejecbqbahwzljelhzxdfdwcmdxipgfczsejxydyewtjrfmyijsqpxayfgbbqfdbjblfdtsraemvehwtkqcekhcsarhtrgicaithtmitnwppbvvtmhihconesvwvmgraecmskglkjptkjzwhcfddijmnshanyvlftperzfxpgccemschpdbemytimjjqlumfqhdbdyykpgeplhwzzokfajaqaeyjfvqgbpaokynqzhgvxckvkxjyfyqrzpijubikprvjozzfvvavlvqhcwevhssjvjgipokegopyfrfffspakxquwtauewztfjrssdmezsaofpwcivroxufzumqarxenowlbwptniayyjnmvchfnqjaeoipskqisoewtzdzoohertdxpfygpgvebqrevbigkbdmdcqrscyrvibgionhodfrhytfvxtrafvtqopatvmtasctxbwmjvhwglvj"
k = 10
```

my code, given the function:

```
def longestIdealString(self, s: str, k: int) -> int:
    L = [1]*len(s)
    dict1 ={}
    for i in range(1,len(s)):
        for j in range(i):
            if s[i]+s[j] not in dict1:
                z = abs(ord(s[i]) - ord(s[j]))
                dict1[s[i]+s[j]] = z
            
            if  dict1[s[i]+s[j]] <= k:
                L[i] = max(L[i],L[j]+1) 
              
    return max(L)
```

Comment: Define "ideal subsequence", please. The OP is unclear. Cite your reference.

Comment: ive updated above.

Comment: It would help if you included that this is a potentially non-contiguous subsequence.

Comment: It doesn't seem terribly useful (other than perhaps as an academic exercise) to calculate the length of the best substring without also providing that substring?

Comment: As an alternative (not really fitting a code review answer), https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145809/linear-programming-for-best-subsequence

Answer (score 1):

In a programming exercise, when your code works for small examples but takes too long for larger problems, it is usually a sign that you need a different algorithm.

The current code is O(n^2) in complexity. So, when the problem doubles in size, the program does 4 times as much work. The code works for s = 'acfgbd', but for a string that is 1000 times longer there is potentially 1_000_000 times more work to do.

#### Another way

Consider `s = 'azab'`, with `k = 2`. After 'aza' is processed, `L = [1, 1, 2, 1]`. When processing the 'b', the leftmost 'a' is within k distance, so L is updated to `L = [1, 1, 2, 2]`. The 'z' is too far away, so L is not updated. Then the rightmost 'a' causes L to be updated to `L = [1, 1, 2, 3]`. Notice that the second 'a' overwrites the result of the first 'a'. This suggests an alternative approach.

Scan `s`, and keep track of the longest sequence seen so far that ends with each letter. When the current letter in `s` is being processed, look at the sequences that end in letters that are reachable from the current letter. Find which sequence is the longest and update the sequence ending at the current letter.

Some code might be easier to understand:

```
def longest_ideal_subsequence(s, k):
    longest_so_far = [0]*26

    for c in s:
        # calculate index into longest_so_far
        index = ord(c) - ord('a')

        # lowest and highest index reachable from `c`
        # watch out for negative indexes wrapping around
        lo = max(index - k, 0)
        hi = index + k + 1

        longest_so_far[index] = max(longest_so_far[lo:hi]) + 1

    return max(longest_so_far)
```

This code is O(n). Each character in `s` is processed once.
On my computer it reduced the run time from about 13s to about 6ms.

Comment: Thanks for the response I really appreciate it.

Comment: so i just tested that algorithm it gave the wrong answer, instead of 3 it gave 4 for the maximum.

Comment: @ColtonF, what was the input that gave the wrong answer?